# JQuery - Find all descendants at any level, but not the descendants of those descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

**QUESTION:**

I am trying to use JQuery's `.find()` to find all descendants within an element **at any level** that have a given attribute, but not the descendants of those descendants with the same attribute.

**TO HELP UNDERSTANDING:**

**JQuery**

The intended goal of the query below is find all descendants within element `$("#some_id")` (at any level) that have `some_attribute` attribute, but not the descendants of those descendants with the same attribute.

```
$("#some_id").find("[some_attribute]");
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="some_id" some_attribute>
    <span some_attribute> <!-- SELECT -->
        <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span some_attribute> <!-- SELECT -->
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
                </span>
            </span>
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- SELECT -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

---

NOTE: I need a generic approach... I explain better! Suppose I don't know the selector `$("#some_id")` I only have the result of that query. Also consider that this result may refer to an element that may be within another element with the `some_attribute` attribute.

Comment: So you want descendants that have an attribute, so long as they are not (in)direct descendants of other elements with that same attribute?

Comment: @Taplar Yes! Exactly! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. For more explanation see the code notes below...

```
// NOTE: Find all descendants at any level, but not the descendants of those descendants.
// By Questor
function findDescsNotDescsOfThose(jqPntElOrPntQry, jqFind){
    var jqElInst;
    if (typeof jqPntElOrPntQry === "string" || 
            jqPntElOrPntQry instanceof String) {
    // [Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436948/3223785 ]

        jqElInst = $(jqPntElOrPntQry);
    } else {
        jqElInst = jqPntElOrPntQry;
    }
    return jqElInst.find(jqFind)
        .filter(function(){

            // NOTE: We need use ".parent ()" and then ".closest ()", otherwise ".closest ()"
            // will find the element itself if it fits "jqFind". By Questor
            descOfjqFind = $(this).parent().closest(jqFind);

            // NOTE: Checks if it is not descended from any element that also fits
            // in "jqFind". Being descended from an element that also fits "jqFind"
            // checks to see if this element is descended from "jqElInst". By Questor
            if (descOfjqFind.length > 0 && $(descOfjqFind).
                    parent().closest(jqElInst).length === 1) {
                return false
            }

            return true;
    });
}
```

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:not` to make sure the selected elements do not match a particular selector - here, `#some_id [some_attribute] [some_attribute]` (because elements which match that selector will be a `some_attribute` nested in another `some_attribute` which is not the `#some_id`):

```js
const result = $("#some_id")
  .find("[some_attribute]:not(#some_id [some_attribute] [some_attribute])")
  .each(function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="some_id" some_attribute>
    <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
        <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
                </span>
            </span>
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

If you can't hard-code it, I suppose a option would be to set an attribute so that you can use `:not` properly:

```js
const elm = $("#some_id");
elm[0].dataset.parent = '';
elm
  .find("[some_attribute]:not([data-parent] [some_attribute] [some_attribute])")
  .each(function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
elm[0].removeAttribute('data-parent');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="some_id" some_attribute>
    <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
        <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
                </span>
            </span>
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

If you don't want to change the DOM either, `.filter` and check that the `.closest` element with `[some_attribute]` is the parent:

```js
const elm = $("#some_id");
elm
  .find("[some_attribute]")
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().closest('[some_attribute]')[0] === elm[0];
  })
  .each(function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="some_id" some_attribute>
    <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
        <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
                </span>
            </span>
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Using old versions of jQuery, you can use `.selector`:

```js
const elm = $("#some_id");
const sel = elm.selector;
elm
  .find(`[some_attribute]:not(${sel} [some_attribute] [some_attribute])`)
  .each(function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="some_id" some_attribute>
    <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
        <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
            <span>
                <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
                </span>
            </span>
            <span some_attribute> <!-- IGNORE -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span some_attribute>sel <!-- SELECT -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I need a more generic approach. I explain better, suppose I don't know the selector `$("#some_id")` I only have the result of that query. Also consider that this result may refer to an element that may be within another element with the `some_attribute` attribute. Thanks! =D

Comment: Maybe some approach that prevents `.find()` from searching within the elements it has already encountered. =D

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/q/38352374/3223785 there's a very similar question. The op presents an answer here https://jsfiddle.net/netaques/sc72fq1x/ . But, it doesn't seem like a good solution... =/

Comment: See edits. You could also use `.selector` in older versions of jQuery, but it's not supported anymore (as of 1.9)

Comment: I'm testing and trying to understand why in my real case it is not working. I will give you feedback! =D

Comment: I tested the solution "If you don't want to change the DOM either [...]" ... But for some reason it didn't work for me in my "real code". I posted a solution on this thread that worked for me (`function findDescsNotDescsOfThose(jqPntElOrPntQry, jqFind)`). Thank you! =D